# Spring Cacheable with Object

Tags: java, spring

I can do the following while using Cacheable:

```
@Cacheable(value = CacheUtil.LEVEL1, key = "'Location'+#root.methodName+'_'+#country+'_'+#lang")
    public List<Location> getCities(String country, String lang)
```

and it works fine.

I am not sure about the following though. How can I cache the following Method with Cacheable?

```
public Content getContent(ContentRequest Request)
```

How should I write the @Cacheable so that It works?

Thanks.

Comment: Apart from a key generator, you can also use a unique property of `Request` as key, like `@Cacheable(value = CacheUtil.LEVEL1, key = "Request.someProperty") public Content getContent(ContentRequest Request)`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need something like this:

```
@Cacheable(value = CacheUtil.LEVEL1, keyGenerator="contentRequestKeyGenerator")
public Content getContent(ContentRequest Request)
```

Where contentRequestKeyGenerator is the name of a bean that implements the KeyGenerator interface see http://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/cache/interceptor/KeyGenerator.html

In the past I have had one bean that does key generation for several different cache classes, in the example below objects[0] is the class of the calling method, ContentRequest in your example :

```
@Component
public class MyKeyGenerator implements KeyGenerator{

    @Override
    public Object generate(Object o, Method method, Object... objects) {
        if (String.class.isInstance(objects[0])) {
            return ....
        }
        else if (....) {

    }
}
```

You would then use this :

```
@Cacheable(value = "properties", keyGenerator = "myKeyGenerator")
public Property getProperty(String key) {
```

Do you need to do this? The default is the hashCode of ContentRequest, usually this is good enough.

Comment: I have many other classes like this. Do I need to implement the above per each?